# How can I get the position(x,y,z) of a 3D Model from 3d Max in xna program

Tags: c#, xna

How can I get the position(x,y,z) of a 3D Model from 3D Max in xna program in order to make a selection between some models

Comment: Please can you explain? @Micky

Comment: I only changed positions of these models in 3D Max and import it in XNA as FBX

Comment: Ah, you'll probably find that when you export from 3ds, the FBX exporter may set the model's mesh coordinates to be relative to the model's origin of (0,0,0) - at least it should

Comment: Yes that's right I want to get the positions of these models according to XNA to be able to select among them @Micky

Answer (score 0):

If you change the positions of the model in 3ds max, then import it into XNA, the position change is written into the root bone transform (which is imported with the model). But to utilize the root bone transform in XNA, you have to apply it with [`Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.model.copyabsolutebonetransformsto.aspx) which will apply the position (and scale, rotation, etc) changes that you made in 3ds max.